# Instabilidade em script para ocultar/mostrar campos

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tenho o seguinte script:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.ocultar').hide();

        $('#dn').change(function () {
            if ($("#dn").attr("checked",true)) {
                $('.ocultar').show();
            }
            else {
                $('.ocultar').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

```
<div id="dn">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.DN) <b>Dpto. Nacional </b>
</div> 

    <div><br /></div>
<div class="ocultar">
  <b> Número do Ofício </b> 
</div>
<div class="ocultar">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Numero)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Numero)
</div>
    <div class="ocultar">
  <b> Observacao </b> 
</div>
<div class="ocultar">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Observacao)
</div>
```

O script funciona direitinho. Carrega a página com os campos em oculto e caso eu marque o checkbox 'DN' os campos 'Numero' e 'Observacao' aparecem. 
Porém tenho dois pequenos problemas: Se eu desmarco o checkbox os dois campos não somem. E se eu deixo marcado e tento salvar, ao clicar no botão salvar, os dois campos somem e a mensagem de que o campo é obrigatório que deveria aparecer, não aparece. Ou seja, quando salva e não passa, carrega o 'hide' novamente. 
Como corrigir essas duas instabilidades?

Answer (score 2):

O erro está nesta linha:

```
if ($("#dn").attr("checked",true)) {
```

O `$("#dn").attr("checked",true)` marca o checkbox como `checked`, e ainda retorna um objeto, o que vai fazer a execução sempre entrar no `if` e nunca no `else`. A solução é bem simples:

```
if ($("#dn").prop("checked")) {
```

Basta não passar o valor, que o o método `attr` passa a retornar o valor atual. Mas repare que eu troquei para [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), que retorna o estado atual do DOM, não o que está no código-fonte do seu HTML. Essa é a maneira recomendada de verificar o estado do checkbox.

Comment: Entendi @bfavaretto. Fiz a alteração para 'prop' mas ao testar e clicar no checkbox nada acontece. Os campos ocultos não aparecem. Falta algo mais?

Comment: Agora que percebi que `#dn` é um div. Tente trocar para `$('#dn input').change...` (troque todos)

Comment: Ok @bfavaretto , resolve um dos problemas que é: se eu marco os campos aparecem, se eu desmarco os campos somem. Beleza. Mas continua o outro. Se eu tento salvar sem preencher o campo 'Numero' os campos somem, ficando assim a mensagem de obrigatoriedade também em oculto entende?

Comment: Na verdade agora a questão passa a ser o _$('.ocultar').hide();_ Quando clico em salvar mas não muda o formulário devido a falha de validação, é como se eu estivesse entrando no formulário pela primeira vez, ou seja, carrega o 'hide'. Como fazer para entender que esse não é o primeiro carregamento da tela e sim que foi falha de validação e os campos devem continuar visíveis e com a mensagem de erro aparente? @bfavaretto

Comment: @PFVictor Acho que isso vale uma pergunta separada, é outro problema.